# Unable to understand a solved problem: Impulse & Impulsive force.

Tags: calculus, physics, mathematical-physics

Why the acceleration $f$ of $m$ to the attached solution of the problem has been taken as $\frac{m-M}{m+M}g$.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since masses $m$ and $M$ are pulling in opposite directions, force acting on the system is $F = (m-M)g$ (these are just gravitational forces). The mass of the system is $m+M$, so by Newton's second law we have $$(m+M)f = (m-M)g$$

Comment: Also, $m > M$ seems as dubious as $\varepsilon < 0$, but I'm not a physicist.